# Kafka Spark Stream save directly to Redis

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, apache-kafka, spark-redis

I'am using Scala to get kafkaStream and want to insert this data directly to Redis. What is the best optimum strategy to do so ?

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "192.168.0.40:2181", "group", topics, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

Earlier I was trying to use https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis but this does not work with Spark so i had to collect the RDD and then save the record into Redis which is creating lot of overhead in my project. So looking for some solution where I can directly push this string of messages into Redis and also want to maintain the ZScore.

Thanks,

Comment: Read your data by batch and insert it into Redis. I tried https://github.com/etaty/rediscala which is quite good.

Comment: How about using Kafka Connect to stream it to Redis? https://github.com/Landoop/stream-reactor/tree/master/kafka-connect-redis

Comment: Is this Jar available on maven ? I can't find ..and how to use this ? Can you please share the code line to connect with Redis and dump data into it.

Comment: @Pinnacle did you https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis ?

Comment: @GuyKorland - no I'm using this https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis